# Race condition with QThread/QDialog

Tags: qt, qthread, qeventloop

I'm trying to avoid a race condition in the following scenario:

```
QDialog* dialog = [...];
QThread* thread = [...];

connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), dialog, SLOT(accept()));

thread->start();
dialog->exec();
```

When the thread finishes before QDialog::exec() has set up the dialog, the "accept()" call that was triggered by the signal will be lost and the dialog will not close itself...

So ideally I want to start the thread only after the dialog is ready to handle it, but how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that you have to start the thread only when the dialog is shown already. so you have to start it once the showEvent of the QDialog is raised.
First you have to capture the showEvent, you can do this by either using `QObject::installEventFilter` and `QObject::eventFilter` or by subclassing `QDialog` overriding `QWidget::showEvent`.
Once you have done that, you want to signal the thread to start. You need a custom signal, which you emit in `YourClass::eventFilter` or in `YourClass::showEvent` depending which way you chose to capture the show event.
Now simply connect that signal to the `QThread::start()` slot and you should be done (EDIT: use a `Qt::QueuedConnection`).

Make sure you dont handle the `QDialog::accepted()` signal twice!

Comment: I think this approach still has a race condition because QDialog::exec() calls show() and only afterwards constructs and executes the event loop...

Comment: @hmn: then use a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, and the singal and wont be emitted until the control returned to the event loop.

Comment: I would need to be a 100% certain that it is the "right" event loop though. Can I be certain that no event loop will be run in between the MyClass::showEvent() and QEventLoop::exec() called from QDialog::exec()?

Comment: @hmn: yes you can, but hmm.. i am unsure now if this approach will work though, i dont know if the local event loop of the dialog will handle our custom signal.. if not, this wont work :( .. well give it a try.

Comment: @hmn: i think you can forget the doubts of my last post, according to some posts of the qt blog local event loops will dispatch events which were raised before the local event loop was started (the example of them was about QObject::deleteLater, but the same should apply to all events which are handled by the event loop)

Answer (score 0):

Was a while since I used Qt. But why are you using a QThread to handle the Accept click from the dialog? You can use QDialog::result() if it's a modal dialog or you can forward the signal from the thread to QDialog::accepted()...